# Get the position of sorted rows

Tags: mysql

How to get position in order, i have make query to back me result and sorted correctly but need to get position because i will make cron and position row will be updated from time to time.

```
SELECT
    users.*,
    (SELECT user_like.likes FROM `user_like`
     WHERE user_like.user_id = users.record_num) AS no_likes,
    (SELECT count(*) FROM user_subscription
     WHERE user_subscription.user_id = users.record_num) AS no_subs
FROM users
ORDER BY no_likes DESC,no_subs DESC,views DESC
```

Comment: Your query could probably be improved, but it looks valid.  Can you show sample output and explain what is wrong with that output?

Comment: Nothing, all is ok, but how to get number of position of sorted rows?

Comment: So you are just looking for a row number, e.g. the first row is 1, second 2, etc.?  What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Yes,version is  5.1.73

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Session variables, you can determine row number. Following solution will work for all the versions of MySQL (especially **< 8.0**).

Try the following query:

```
SET @row_number = 0;
SELECT 
  @row_number := @row_number + 1 as row_no, 
  derived_t.* 
FROM 
(
SELECT

    users.*,
    (SELECT user_like.likes FROM `user_like`
     WHERE user_like.user_id = users.record_num) AS no_likes,
    (SELECT count(*) FROM user_subscription
     WHERE user_subscription.user_id = users.record_num) AS no_subs
FROM users
ORDER BY no_likes DESC, 
         no_subs DESC, 
         views DESC
) AS derived_t
```

**Details**:

- In the first statement, we defined a variable named row_number and set its value to 0. The row_number is a session variable indicated by the **@** prefix.
- In the Select statement, we increased the value of the `@row_number` variable to 1 for each row.

Comment: Does not work correctly, first sorted row is back me as row_no 1023

Comment: @Jony1998 can you give some sample data and output as per my query

Comment: This is screen how is back me result, should be 1,2,3,4,5,6... etc.
https://i.imgur.com/gJwWWqI.png

Comment: @Jony1998 I have updated the query. Can u check it now please!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a row number counter along with your sorted result set, we can use a user variable for that.  But, you should also refactor your query to use joins to do those aggregations, rather than correlated subqueries:

```
SET @rn = 0;

SELECT *,
    (@rn:=@rn + 1) AS position
FROM
(
    u.*,
    COALESCE(ul.likes, 0) AS no_likes,
    COALESCE(us.no_subs, 0) AS no_subs
    FROM users u
    LEFT JOIN user_like ul
        ON u.record_num = ul.user_id
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS no_subs
        FROM user_subscription
        GROUP BY user_id
    ) us
        ON us.user_id = u.record_num
) t
ORDER BY
    no_likes DESC,
    no_subs DESC,
    views DESC;
```

Note that if you are using MySQL 8+ or later, than you can just use the built in analytic function `ROW_NUMBER` with an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Hmm Unknown column 'ul.user_id' in 'on clause'